# Remove empty and cells from array (same key/value pairs)

Tags: php, pdo

Hi I know that array_filter function can be used to remove null and empty values from the array. But not when every key in the array is the same.

```
$array4 = array('bean1' => 'blue', 'bean2' => null, 'bean3' => 'red', 'bean4' => 'white');
$keynull = array_search(null, $array4);
$firephp -> info('$Keynull = '.$keynull);

if($keynull)
{
    $firephp -> info('There is one or more null or empty strings in $array4!, so clean it up');
    $arrayfiltered = array_filter($array4);
    $firephp -> info($arrayfiltered);

};
```

Above script can work. But what if I used bean, instead of bean#, see below....

```
$array4 = array('bean' => 'blue', 'bean' => null, 'bean' => 'red', 'bean' => 'white');
$keynull = array_search(null, $array4);
$firephp -> info('$Keynull = '.$keynull);

if($keynull)
{
    $firephp -> info('There is one or more null or empty strings in $array4!, so clean it up');
    $arrayfiltered = array_filter($array4);
    $firephp -> info($arrayfiltered);

};
```

It does not seem to work. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, it makes perfect sense because array cannot have 4 value with the same key. Basically, the value of the key get override with the latest assigned value. To see a clear picture:

---

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('bean1' => 'blue', 'bean2' => null, 
                    'bean3' => 'red', 'bean4' => 'white');
    print_r($array1);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [bean1] => blue
    [bean2] => 
    [bean3] => red
    [bean4] => white
)
```

---

```
<?php
     $array2 = array('bean' => 'blue', 'bean' => null, 
                     'bean' => 'red', 'bean' => 'white');
     print_r($array2);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [bean] => white
)
```

---

I don't know whether this will help, but instead of filter using PHP, why not filter directly with SQL?

```
SELECT batch FROM test 
WHERE  mfg_code = mfgnum AND
       batch IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY batch ORDER BY batch DESC;
```

This will work regardless of any fetch mode.

Comment: What is the better solution?

Comment: Why do you want to have the same key with multiple value?

Comment: That's the way it became after I query from database. Woul it better to add increment values to every key after I query? How do I add increment to these keys after querying?

Comment: I doubt database query would return such way. Please post how you retrieve your data from database and what the data would look like.

Comment: Here's the schema for this table:    mysql> show create table test\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID_test` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `mfg_code` varchar(24) default NULL,
  `batch` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `tested` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `SN` varchar(12) default NULL,
  `ID_jig` smallint(5) default NULL,
  `status` char(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID_test`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=49404 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Use this '$result = $stmt_call2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);' to query where 'SELECT batch FROM test WHERE mfg_code = mfgnum group by batch order by batch desc;'. Then result: {"data":[{"batch":"0010006363"},{"batch":"0010005459"},{"batch":"0010004582"},{"batch":"0010003604"},{"batch":"0010002940"},{"batch":"0010000933"},{"batch":"0010000928"},{"batch":"00016591"},{"batch":"000005467"},{"batch":"0000050004"},{"batch":"0000049642"},{"batch":"0000049301"},{"batch":"0000047127"},{"batch":"0000046195"},{"batch":"0000040764"},{"batch":"0000038687"},{"batch":"0000037497"},"index":{"undefined":86}}

Comment: Using PHP's PDO, I use 'fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)' to fetch all data before performing array_search and array_filter of $result for any null values.

Comment: I realised that it has to do with fetch_style and fetch_agrument. You can read [link](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). So how do I get indexed associative array?

Comment: I can't seem to get it right after numerous tries with fetch_style and fetch_agruments. Pls help

Comment: I want to include if there is any null, so that my program can further query if there is  any null or not. What I mean is that I can query further later on if batch is a null. I think it works only if fetch_style and fetch_agrument are correctly applied. It's not really about null. Rather it is about constructing it into indexed associative array.